# Mutliple Errors Module Not Found Angular when building app

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I have a Angular project, using Visual Studio code (updated today if this matters). Before the update the application was working, but a few hours ago when trying to build the project I am getting these errors below.

I have removed the node_modules folder, and ran npm-install again, but i keep getting the same error. The node_modules folder is present.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxLTs.jpg)

Here are my angular.json values:

`"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.0.2",
    "node-modules": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
}`

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. It seems that those errors are coming from importing a library from a wrong path - in my case firebase-admin.